# Why there is "none" when i try to count odd numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what i want:

> count odd numbers of list a

my code as following:

```
def find_it(seq):
    set_seq=set(seq)
    dict_seq = {}
    for item in set_seq:
        dict_seq.update({item:seq.count(item)})
    print(dict_seq)

a=[20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]
print(find_it(a))
```

This outputs:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 20: 2, -2: 2, -1: 2}
None
```

Why does it output `None`?

Comment: Are you missing a `return` statement in that function? The program is outputting the result of calling the function, and since it doesn't have a `return` statement, the result is `None`.

Comment: add `return dict_seq` in function

Comment: thank you so much!!!how can i give the thumbs-up to you on website?i'm not familar on stackover...

Answer (score 0):

You do not return anything so there is nothing to be print. Here is the answer yo are looking for!!

```
def find_it(seq):
    set_seq=set(seq)
    dict_seq = {}
    for item in set_seq:
        dict_seq.update({item:seq.count(item)})
    return dict_seq

a=[20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]
my_dict = find_it(a)
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: why `my_dict = find_it(a)`, why not just `print(find_it(a))`

Comment: just for visual purposes! in order to show you that from the function find_it something is returned and afterwords you can do anything with it

Answer (score 0):

#### Counting the odd numbers

To count the odd numbers, after reducing to a set you should run the a loop looking at `%2` append that number to a list (or increment a counter). Since you seem to be fairly new, here's an easy to understand approach:

```
def find_it(seq):
    set_seq=set(seq)
    odds=[]
    for item in set_seq:
        if item%2==1:
            odds.append(item)
    return len(odds)
```